# How can I send string to input <type = "email"> with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate a login with Selenium in python, but the the tag type is "email", and dosen't have the 'send_keys' atribute nether the 'click' atribute

I selected the tag with xpath:

```
email_xpath = '//input[@name="email_address"]'
email_box = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(email_xpath)
```

when i try to force i receive this message:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabriel/PycharmProjects/Webnars/webnarJam Sing Up.py", line 78, in <module>
    email_box.send_keys(target[1])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Has some way to type our send keys to a input tag type "email"?

Comment: `'list' object` seems to me as if there are multiple of such element**s** (`find_elements...`) that match the XPath. Try `email_box[0].send_keys(...)`

Comment: I can belive i do that. I spend more than 3 hours loking for it. Thank you for the help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath()` returns a *list* of elements.

If you only expect to find one element, use `find_element_by_xpath()` instead.

Otherwise, if you do expect to find multiple elements, you'll have to pull each element out of the list.

Comment: I can belive i do that. I spend more than 3 hours loking for it. Thank you for the help